# Is there a way to pass a prop image in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image

I am having an issue passing a prop image are there any issues with my code?

**Home Screen code: **

```
const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) =>
{

  const [shoes, setShoes] = useState([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const fetchData = async () =>
    {
        const receivedShoes = await fetch(`http://192.168.8.103:8080/shoes`)
        const receivedShoesJSON = await receivedShoes.json()
        setShoes(receivedShoesJSON)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData();
    });

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {isLoading ? (<ActivityIndicator/>) :
        (<FlatList data={shoes} keyExtractor={({id}) => id} renderItem={({item}) =>(
          <ShoeDisplay brand = {item.brand} name = {item.name} price = {item.price} image = {item.photoLocation}/>
          )} />
        )}
        <StatusBar style="auto" /> 
      </View>
        
    )
}
```

photoLocation looks like this - "photoLocation":"../client/public/images/1685958934714.jpeg"

I am doing the substring as I want to remove the ../client I know it's not optimal but this is not my issue

I tried source={image} with the image being

```
const image = require(`..` + props.image.substring(9))
```

This results in Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../public/images/1685958934714.jpeg'

and the one that you see below

**Shoe Display code: **

```
const ShoeDisplay = (props) =>
{

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri:`..${props.image.substring(9)}`}}/>
            <Text style={styles.brand} id="brand">{props.brand}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.name} id="display-title">{props.name}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.price} id="price">€{props.price}</Text> 
        </View>
    )
    
}
```

This does not show any errors however does not show the photo either.

Comment: if all your images are in public then just use this src `/images/1685958934714.jpeg` instead of `../xxx/xxx/xxx/`

Comment: Nope, does not resolve the issue sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string by "\" and then get the last element of the resulting array. Let's call that element 'imageId'.

Then, use

```
const image = require(`../public/images` + imageId)
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, however we run into a different problem now. It runs perfectly on web, bi=ut The expo on my simulator gives me an Invalid call at line 49.